# jqGrid not displaying row in MVC 4.0

Tags: jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried and I finally give up trying to figure out why my jqGrid doesn't display data.

Let me try and go step-by-step:
The below is what is included for the script...

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/redmond/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The JSON returned:

```
{
"total": 1,
"page": 1,
"records": 1,
"rows": [
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "cell": [
            "0001",
            "XXXXX",
            "XXXX",
            "XXX",
            "XXX",
            "XXXXX",
            "XXXX",
            "7/27/2012 1:46:22 PM",
            "XXXXX",
            "7/30/2012 3:48:25 PM"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The jqGrid Code is as follows:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery('#tblManageApplication').jqGrid({
        url: '/AdminView/ManageApplicationsJQGridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(status + " " + error); }, 
        mtype: 'GET', 
        colNames: ['Application ID', 'Application Name', 'Application Description', 'Country Code', 'Country Name', 'Source Indicator Code', 'Insert User ID', 'Insert User Timestamp', 'Update User ID', 'Update User Timestamp'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'ApplicationID', jsonmap: 'cell.ApplicationID', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'ApplicationName', jsonmap: 'cell.ApplicationName', width: 200 },
                    { name: 'ApplicationDescription', jsonmap: 'cell.ApplicationDescription', width: 250 },
                    { name: 'CountryCode', jsonmap: 'cell.CountryCode', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'CountryName', jsonmap: 'cell.CountryName', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'SourceIndicatorCode', jsonmap: 'cell.SourceIndicatorCode', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'InsertUserID', jsonmap: 'cell.InsertUserID', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'InsertUserTimestamp', jsonmap: 'cell.InsertUserTimestamp', width: 100, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-m-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-m-Y' },
                    { name: 'UpdateUserID', jsonmap: 'cell.UpdateUserID', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'UpdateUserTimestamp', jsonmap: 'cell.UpdateUserTimestamp', width: 175, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'd-m-Y'}, datefmt: 'd-m-Y' }
                  ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        sortName: 'ApplicationID',
        rowNum: 10,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
        rowList: [10, 20, 50],
        sortorder: 'desc',
        height: 300,
        width: 1200,
        caption: 'Manage Applications',
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, index, contents, event) {
            alert('onCellSelect: ' + index + ' : ' + contents);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == 'success') {
                alert('Successful');
            }
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus) {
            alert('An error has occurred');
        }
    });
});
```

Wanted to add the corresponding HTML for your reference:

```
<table id="tblManageApplication"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the onCellSelect method, I get the following alert displayed:

onCellSelect: 1 &nbsp;

The index is correctly displayed, but the contents is always &nbsp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error in your code is the usage of `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` option and `jsonmap` in the case where you don't need there at all. You produce the data in the standard format. So you have to remove the options to be able to fill the grid.

Additionally I would recommend you to change the data format to [ISO 8601](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (you can use "o" format of `DateTime` on the server code) or at least define correct `srcformat`:

```js
formatoptions: {srcformat: 'm/d/Y g:i:s A', newformat: 'd-m-Y'}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhisheikDeo.htm) demonstrate that the changes which I described above working.

Comment: I was able to get the grid to display data, but didn't realize that the issue was due to the use of both jsonReader: { repeatitems: false } and jsonmap options. I now only use the jsonmap option and it works.

Answer (score 2):

first, can you confirm that that data you are sending from controller and colModal names are same alphabetically?

second check your json reader

check this link

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ipInfo.htm  i think you need to specify a couple of things here like id and records.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Piyush. The reason for the grid not displaying data in the grid is answered by Oleg.